# How to do direct memory addessing in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64, emulation, nasm, jit

I have a intel syntax assembly like this:

```
    global doAddition
    doAddition:
    mov rax, [0xFFFF]
    mov rdx, [0xFFFF]
    add rax, rdx
    mov [0xFFFF], rax
    ret
```

I'm trying to create a JIT dynarec for CHIP8. How can I access C pointers in assembly? This is a test example code that gives me segfault once I try to get value at that address. Go part of dynarec is just putting pointers to values into that 0xFFFF space. So what am I doing wrong? If I look at memory, it seems OK to me, the pointers seem to be in place.

Comment: How are the C pointers passed to your function?  You need to know the calling conventions for your platform.  "Go part of dynarec is just putting pointers to values into that 0xFFFF space." I don't understand what you mean by that.  Your program is trying to fetch from absolute virtual address 0xffff and in general there is no reason to think that page is mapped, so you get a fault.

Comment: Can you point to the documentation you're trying to follow?

Comment: I'm not following any docs. That's just an example code, I feed some bytes(generated by the assembler out of that piece of code) to a JIT block(the values 0xFFFF are just markers to make it easier for me to see where the actual pointer can be located), and replace those 0xFFFF with the actual pointer, then execute the block.

Comment: When you single-step with a debugger in that JITed block, what do you see?  Is that machine code using the correct addresses with `[abs  disp32]` addressing modes, or still the placeholders?  Also, NASM might use `[abs disp64]` for the load and store of RAX, so double-check whether you get the same address format for it as for the non-RAX load.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov.  Also, include details like this in your question.  It makes no sense without your followup comment in reply to Nate.